# The version of Microsoft.NET.Sdk used by this project is insufficient to support references to libraries targeting .NET Standard 1.5 or higher

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-2.0

Im am encountering the following build error:

> The version of Microsoft.NET.Sdk used by this project is insufficient to support references to libraries targeting .NET Standard 1.5 or higher.  Please install version 2.0 or higher of the .NET Core SDK.

[image]

Whenever I'm rebuilding a solution, this error will show. Has anybody a clue how to solve this? I'm sure I've installed Visual Studio 2017 (15.3.2) and .NET Core 2.0 properly.

[image]

Comment: Try installing .Net Core 2.0 SDK instead of binaries..

Comment: https://www.microsoft.com/net/download/core - has the option to download SDK

Comment: edit the question and upload third picture as well

Comment: I've had this error too. In my case was due to duplicate/reuse a publish profile from another project, so this error started appearing when trying to publish. Created a new one from scratch and voila. This was project was indeed using NETStandard 2.0

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I had the same issue. Adding `<DependsOnNETStandard>false</DependsOnNETStandard>` to your `csproj` file works for now. Have a look at https://github.com/dotnet/sdk/issues/1527 for more information.

Comment: Good to hear. Please keep an eye on the issue/announcements repository of ASP.NET Core, MS might fix this issue in a future release.

Comment: but now the solution is not base on standard 2.0，too wish to one day that standard become the real "standard"

Comment: Yeah, I'm upgrading my systems to .NET Core 2.0/.NET Standard 2.0 as well, loads more API's and improvements that we actually need. If you want, you can mark my answer as the solution to your question. That also helps people coming by later.

Comment: This is what I've been looking for since yesterday! Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

**What doesn't work (for me)?**

- I uninstalled VS2017, uninstalled all Dotnet related things from
  Control Panel, reinstalled everything again. Still, I got the same
  error. I uninstalled dotnet core versions and reinstalled them and it
  doesn't work.
- "Adding
  false to your csproj
  file" **kind of worked** but this problem was only on my machine and I
  didn't want to use that if I don't have to.

**What worked (for me)?**

I opened targets file

> C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\MSBuild\Microsoft\Microsoft.NET.Build.Extensions\Microsoft.NET.Build.Extensions.NETFramework.targets

Deleted this line

```
<NETBuildExtensionsError Condition="'$(DependsOnNETStandard)' == 'true' AND '$(NETStandardInbox)' != 'true' AND '$(_UsingOldSDK)' == 'true'" ResourceName="UnsupportedSDKVersionForNetStandard20"/>
```

Comment: Did the same for Mono: `/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/6.13.0/lib/mono/xbuild/Microsoft/Microsoft.NET.Build.Extensions/Microsoft.NET.Build.Extensions.NETFramework.targets` and it works. Thanks!

Comment: @VictorTrusov appreciate upvote. I'm glad it helped

Answer (score 1):

You need to install `.Net Core SDK 2.0` along with `.Net 2.0 binaries (Runtime)`. Please install the .Net Core 2.0 SDK based on your Target platform of your project either `x86` or `x64`

.Net Core SDK 2.0 download from [here](https://www.microsoft.com/net/download/core)

[image: Sample]

Comment: yes,i have done it.ican only upload two pictures before post ten posts.actually my third picture is that :dotnet --info  and the result shows i have installed .net core 2.0

Comment: Ok. But, if you are using SDK, then need to install SDK as well. There is not enough to install Binaries (Runtime) alone.

Comment: you mean that have to install both .net core sdk 2.0 and .net core runtime 2.0? i have installed .net core sdk what i'm sure.so i have to install runtime?

Comment: Have you seen SDK node inside dependencies as shown in above image? If yes, then please check the Target platform of your application. And make sure you were installing corresponding SDK (x86 or x64) in your system. If problem presist, install binaries (either x86 or x64) based on your application's target platform.

Comment: i find a problem,my target is framework not core, does standard 2.0 not support framework now?

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same issue a few days ago. and Adding `<DependsOnNETStandard>` can not solve my problem. I just uninstalled the 'Microsoft .NET Core …' in Control Pannel. And then install the .net core again. This problem disappeared. Maybe it is a fastest way to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

On my side, I have to add the following to `.csprj`:

```
<PropertyGroup>
  <DependsOnNETStandard>netstandard2.0</DependsOnNETStandard>
</PropertyGroup>
```

```
<ItemGroup>
  <Reference Include="netstandard" />
</ItemGroup>
```